# How to return 1/0 if a condition is met using MySQL

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I have the following query:

```
SELECT l.id as 'Representative ID', l.created_at as 'Time of Submission', 
cmr.created_at as 'First Client', 
time_to_sec(timediff(cmr.created_at, l.created_at))/3600 as 'Delta (hrs)'
FROM representatives l
INNER JOIN clients cmr
ON cmr.id = ( 
                SELECT id FROM clients
                WHERE representative_id = l.id
                ORDER BY created_at ASC
                LIMIT 1
            );
```

All good there, I'm getting all the representative and their first associated client.

Now, I want to add a new column to the result set. I want a column named "Client hired Representative" and it should say "1 or 0" (true or false) if:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE representative_id = l.id AND clients.hired_at IS NOT NULL
```

I'm not sure how to incorporate that to my current query and how to get the 1/0 result.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: please describe the tables

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following

```
CASE WHEN cmr.hired_at IS NOT NULL 
       THEN 1
       ELSE 0
END AS "Client hired Representative"
```

or

```
(cmr.hired_at IS NOT NULL) AS "Client hired Representative"
```

It only has the hired_at condition since you are doing an inner join on `representative_id = 1.id` which will eliminate all the records that do not match

Comment: But my join has a LIMIT 1 and suppose that one has hired_at == NULL, that doesn't mean the are not any associated clients to that representative with hired_at != NULL

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` statement will do the work like below

```
case when clients.hired_at IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end 
as 'Client hired Representative'
```

So your original query should look like

```
   SELECT ID,col1,col2,col3,
    case when clients.hired_at IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end 
    as 'Client hired Representative'
   FROM clients 
   WHERE representative_id = l.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my query was:

```
SELECT l.id as 'Doctor ID', l.created_at as 'Time of Submission',
cmr.created_at as 'First Client',
time_to_sec(timediff(cmr.created_at, l.created_at))/3600 as 'Delta (hrs)',
CASE WHEN cmrs.id IS NOT NULL
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS 'At least 1 hire'
FROM doctors l
LEFT JOIN clients cmr
ON cmr.id = (
SELECT id FROM clients
WHERE doctor_id = l.id
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 1
)
LEFT JOIN clients cmrs
ON cmrs.id = (
SELECT id FROM clients
WHERE doctor_id = l.id
AND hired_at IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
IF(IS NULL(cmr.hired_at), 0, 1) AS 'Client Hired Representative'
```